# "Asked" or "Modified"?

Tags: bug, questions, live-refresh

I have noticed the following weird behavior on PSE and MSE, and I believe it probably applies to many more SE websites :

whenever one loads the 'new' tab for questions, all the questions displayed are shown with a "asked xx minutes ago" text. However when new questions come in, they are displayed with a "modified xx seconds ago" text. Why is that ?

[image]

Comment: Reproed on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: @ShadowWizard True, but that one has no answers

Comment: So? It's still a dupe. It might take years for a bug to be fixed, it doesn't mean we should have 100 open reports.

Comment: @Tim it's cross-network, happening in all 140+ sites - it's in the very "core" of the codebase.

Comment: Please don't pollute the report with noise - dupes are fine, but should be closed, that's all.